# a change with visudo doesn't work

Tags: sudo, visudo

I issue visudo command, add this rule to the very end of the file, save the file and quit.

```
newuser    ALL=/usr/sbin/useradd
```

However newuser is still able to run such commands as

```
sudo passwd username
```

And the added rule to sudoers file seems not to work. Why ?

I have logged out/in after modifying the file.

The goal is to make newuser be able to create a new user but not be able to set a password for that user.

```
id newuser
uid=1003(newuser) gid=1003(newuser) groups=1003(newuser),27(sudo)


visudo


#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:    /usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

newuser     ALL=/usr/sbin/useradd
```

Comment: `passwd` is NOT the same as the `useradd` command - you have to add *each* command accordingly to the thing.  So `passwd` is actually a command you have to specify on the config as well, with a line afterwards defining that the user is allowed to execute that command as sudo too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `newuser` has two lines that can affect it in your configuration.  It belongs to `sudo` group, and is the user `newuser`.  Because your user is in `sudo` group, it can run any command after providing the password.

You need to remove `newuser` from the `sudo` group, or adjust your configuration to suit this.  Be careful that you don't lose `sudo` from your main account during this process!

When `newuser` is no longer in a group that gives it access to all commands, it will be restricted and only allowed to run `useradd`, as you've configured, and there will be no need to mess with or add any `passwd` entries, as it will have no access to that command.

---

The wording of your question is unclear.  Is `newuser` able to, or not able to run any and all `sudo` commands?  Can they or can they not run `sudo passwd username`?  What is your goal?

You'll have to give us the `/etc/sudoers` file, as well as list of groups to which your `newuser` belongs.  It is likely `newuser` is in the `sudo` group, or some other group being given access.

If you cannot run `sudo passwd`, you need to add a rule to allow your user to run the command, since `/usr/sbin/useradd` and `/usr/bin/passwd` are two different binaries.

Have you thought of the consequences of what you're doing?  If you allow `newuser` to `sudo passwd root`, why not just give them root access (unless you actually lock it down to `username`)?

Comment: Earthmelon, thank you for your response and I love your nickname :]